# Getting error while converting any python file to exe with auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

When converting any python file to exe, I get an error

```
Error processing line 1 of c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 576, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 359, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Error processing line 1 of c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 576, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 359, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Error processing line 1 of c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 576, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 359, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Error processing line 1 of c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 576, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 359, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
26547 ERROR: An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\mehme\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpug4gvv84\MAIN.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['C:/Users/mehme/Desktop/Github/SpotifyLyrics/MAIN.py'],
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 467, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 304, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).add_script(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_module
    hook_module.pre_safe_import_module(hook_api)
  File "c:\users\mehme\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py", line 33, in pre_safe_import_module
    raise SystemExit("pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.")
SystemExit: pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.
```

- I saw on the internet that it might be related to the code inside of
  the python files. Then I created a new python file and typed
  `print(1+2)` into it. then i tried to convert again. but same
  error has occured.
- I tried to uninstall pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe and install them
  again. nothing changed

Comment: Please post code and errors as `formatted text`, not links or images

Comment: @ForceBru it was too long. that was why i wanted to share with link but i edited it now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip uninstall -y enum34
```

is worked for me.